# Object doesn't support property or method 'pause'

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, video, microsoft-edge

I've got a React app that has a `<video>` element:

```
<video controls ref={e => this.video = e} />
```

It has a bug in Microsoft Edge v14. No bug in Edge v13 and earlier IE versions. This line throws `Object doesn't support property or method 'pause'`:

```
this.video.pause()
```

Since the bug is only present in Edge v14, I think Microsoft needs to fix this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNzaVw?editors=1111

I'm confused and unable to debug this, does anyone have any suggestion or workaround?

EDIT: Found the problem. This bug isn't related to React. I was running Edge on Windows 10 Enterprise N and it turns out the N edition doesn't support the HTML5 video tag in Edge or Internet Explorer. You can check that here: https://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: First, the video element is not self closing.

Comment: Rob: Doesn't matter in JSX

Comment: a little bit of sick came out.  Any idea why this is?

Comment: @PaulHodgson Huh? Not sure what you mean.